# Is there any method to pass protobuf object to shared_ptr?

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers

I want to copy protobuf msg "SmConfig" to an shared_ptr like below:

```
SignalMachine::SignalMachine(SmConfig* sm_config) {
  sm_config_ = std::make_shared<SmConfig>();
  sm_config_.CopyFrom(*sm_config);
}

class SignalMachine {
 private:
  std::shared_ptr<SmConfig> sm_config_;
}
```

Because I need to keep SmConfig(protobuf) in "class SignalMachine", I used the above method, is it reasonable? in fact, I did not find the corresponding description in the official document.

Comment: See for_stack's anwer. As a side node: If you take a look into the generated code you'll find out that the copy constructors looks like this: inline SignalMachine& operator=(const SignalMachine& from) {    CopyFrom(from);    return *this;  }

Comment: You mean？  inline SmConfig& operator=(const SmConfig& from) { CopyFrom(from); return *this; }

Comment: uhhh, sorry - used the wrong name Yes, I meant SmConfig. It was meant as a helpful hint, if you look into the code generated by Protobuf you will often find quite helpful details/methods

Comment: Thx! I think the encapsulation of protobuf is easy and friendly, but it encapsulates too much memory management, which leads to the need to read the memory ownership in the API in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use copy constructor:

```
SignalMachine::SignalMachine(SmConfig* sm_config) {
  if (sm_config != nullptr)
    sm_config_ = std::make_shared<SmConfig>(*sm_config);
  // else error handling
}
```

Comment: Thx for your kindly reply!  Can copy construction copy all objects? and "sm_config_" can be released automatically. if I add some objects in sm_config_ use protobuf add api, can I still release the memory correctly?

Comment: YES, its copy constructor and destructor are well defined. No need to worry about that.